# CARQuery API in Contact form 7 for Wordpress. Some custom code

Tags: wordpress, api

Hello i am new to the community with little knowledge of coding but with huge interest to grow bigger and bigger in the knowledge. Sorry if my English is bad, i am Bulgarian.
So, recently i've isntalled CARQuery API for Wordpress. I need a contact form 7 with Year/make/model/trim dropdown fields and submit them to email. Everything is fine except the TRIM field...instead of engine size i get numbers like 74567, 34567 and so on..

This is the otput in email:

```
Vehichle Info

Year: 2001
Make: opel
Model: Zafira
Trim: 30538
```

it should be

```
Vehichle Info

Year: 2001
Make: opel
Model: Zafira
Trim: 2.0 Diesel
```

Until now i am using shortcodes for the dropdowns:

```html
[select* cq-year id:cq-year]
[select* cq-make id:cq-make]
[select* cq-model id:cq-model]
[select* cq-trim id:cq-trim]

[submit "SEND"]
```

and a function in functions.php

```html
add_action('init','load_carquery_api_scripts');
function load_carquery_api_scripts() {
    if (class_exists('CarQueryAPI')) {
        CarQueryAPI::$add_script = true;
    }
}
```

What could be the solutions for trim? Is there a way the get data from dropdown TRIM field and export it as text. Here is the test page:

https://car.avtopedia.com/?page_id=7285

In the page the TRIM is visualised correctly...so for me the solution is to read the data and convert it to text or something ... i do not know. Could somebody help ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found for having the trim not be sent through my contact form as an ID was within the Javascript file linked within the carquery-api.php file.

On line 107:

> ```
> wp_register_script('carquery-api-js', 'https://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js', array('jquery'),
> ```
>
> '0.3.4', true);

I went to that file, copied it, and on line 867 I changed the 'trim_id' to 'model_id'

Looking like this below:

```
options += '<option value="' + trims[i].model_trim + '" '+s+'>' +  trim_display + '</option>';
```

Now when I fill out my form using the selectors, it will use the model name rather than the model's ID number.

Sorry this is late. Hope this helps anyone who might need it!

Comment: This worked for me. I believe this should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks @Troy your awesome!