# Carquery API used in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, api, contact-form-7

I downloaded Carquery API and used it on the form. This form should send the client's information including the carquery's car year/make/model/trim data to the email. All the information are correct except for the trim. The trim sends numbers (6306, 7725, 30538) instead of the actual car model trim.

The information I selected on the carquery dropdown menu on the form:

Year: 2016
Make: BMW
Model: M3
Trim: 4dr Sedan (3.0L 6cyl Turbo

What I received on the email:

Year: 2016
Make: BMW
Model: M3
Trim: 66203

I saw another similar problem with answer here on stackflow but I wasn't able to make it work. ([CARQuery API in Contact form 7 for Wordpress. Some custom code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088704/carquery-api-in-contact-form-7-for-wordpress-some-custom-code/67630329#67630329))

I went to the Javascript file linked within the carquery-api.php file. And went to line 107

```
wp_register_script('carquery-api-js', 'https://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js', array('jquery'),
```

I opened https://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js. I checked the code on line 867 and this is the code

```
options += '<option value="' + trims[i].model_trim + '" '+s+'>' +  trim_display + '</option>';
```

The previous solution says that I need to change the trim_id to model_id. My question is, do I need to copy the whole code, edit it and save it in another file the link line 107 to the new file? I can't find the trim_id and model_id on line 867, how can I change it?

Thank you for your help. If there are other ways to fix the trim data, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line..

```
options += '<option value="' + trims[i].model_id + '" '+s+'>' +  trim_display + '</option>';
```

.. with:

```
options += '<option value="' + trim_display + '" '+s+'>' +  trim_display + '</option>';
```

or console.log(trims[i]) so that you can see the returned values and go on from there. Above the line, add this..

```
console.log(trims[i])
```

.., then go to the site or app and check the returned value in the browser console.

Just keep in mind that whatever value you used in the option's value attribute is the value that is going to be reflected in the email.

Comment: I copied the file from https://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.4.js edited it, replaced the line with  

options += '<option value="' + trim_display + '" '+s+'>' +  trim_display + '</option>';

and created a newfile on my github with this code. I changed the link on line 107 and redirected it to the edited file on github but when I tried my form, it doesn't show the data with the carquery

Comment: Did you try to console.log the value of the trims[i] as suggested above? It should contain all the data about the car trim, then you can select which data you would like to include in the email by assigning it as the value of the option field.

Comment: Yes I put the console.log(trims[i]) above line 867. But still didn't show data on the form